# React Material-UI Tabs Container

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

See the picture attached, I want the container of the tab (red) fill out the whole content of the tab/paper:
[image]

My code is directly copied from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs just wrapped inside a paper element.

Comment: Try removing all padding from the Paper element, and setting the containers height and width to 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Setting the container height to 100% did work, however it is off now. I want it to fit onto my paper component.